# Enter a new line in java servlet in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, neo4j

I am working on an webapplication and i have a neo4j database connected to it.
I am using a iterator to find all the nodes like this:

```
 Iterator<Node> list_brands = result.columnAs("n");
        while (list_brands.hasNext()) {
            Node brand = list_brands.next();
            out.println(brand.getProperty("Titel", "null"));

        }
```

So this code gives me all the nodes with the property "Titel"
I want each name on a new line.

I've tried like everything but nothing worked like:

```
/n, /r/n, System.getProperty(line.separator);
```

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: You want each property on a new line in the resulting HTML? If so, use HTML markup for linebreaks, i.e. `<br/>` etc.  Btw, the literals for line breaks in plain text are `\n` and  `\r`, not `/n` and `/r`.

Comment: Can u please show me how to implement <br/> in my code. I tried like this:  out.println(brand.getProperty("Titel<br/>")); This does  not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!

My ajax code was not correct. My servlet was doing good with the html tags, but if i made an ajax call to get data from the servlet it wouldn't recognize the html tags in my servlet. This is the ajax code bellow for the people getting the same problem:

```
function data(){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#moeder').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'MyServlet',
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'html',
        success : function(result) {
            jQuery("#ajaxGetUserServletResponse").html(result); //i added this line and it worked.

        }
    });
});
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the comments, you need to use HTML linebreaks (`<br/>`) to get them in the browser.

`out.println(brand.getProperty("Titel<br/>"));` won't work, since I assume there's no property with that name.

Instead you need to write `<br/>` to your JSP, e.g. by calling

```
out.print(brand.getProperty("Titel")); //no println() here, because newline is not needed
out.print("<br/>"); //write the html tag to the JSP's output stream
```

Btw, I'd probably check whether that property exists before trying to print it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually don't know where JSP's output stream is. So i put the code out.print("<br/>") under out.print(brand.getProperty("Titel")); If i only run the servlet, the data is good. if i run my application and i click on my button then i get the data with literally the text <br/> between the data.